# extracting main URL address

Tags: r, url, stringr

I have a list of URLs and I want to extract the main URL to see how many times each URL has been used. as you can imagine, there are so many URLs with different notations. I tried and wrote the following code to extract the main URL:

```
library(stringr)
library(rebus)

# Step 2: creating a pattern for URL extraction
pat<- "//" %R% capture(one_or_more(char_class(WRD,DOT)))

#step 3: Creating a new variable from URL column of df
#(it should be atomic vector)
URL_var<-df[["URLs"]]  

#step 4: using rebus to extract main URL
URL_extract<-str_match(URL_var,pattern = pat)

#step 5: changing large vector to dataframe and changing column name:
URL_data<-data.frame(URL_extract[,2])
names(URL_data)[names(URL_data) == "URL_extract...2."] <- "Main_URL"
```

The result of this code is acceptable for most cases. For example for **//www.google.com**, it returns **[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)** and for a website like **http://image.google.com/steve** it returns **image.google.com**; however, there are so many cases that this code can't recognize the pattern and will fail to find the URL. For example for URL such as **http://my-listing.ca/CommercialDrive.html** the code will return **my** which is definitely not acceptable. for another example, for a website like **http://www.real-data.ca/clients/ur/** it only returns **www.real**. It seems that handling **-** for my code is difficult

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this code? or do we have any packages to help me extract URLs faster and better?

Thanks

Comment: Try without `rebus`, just `URL_data<-data.frame(str_extract(URL_var, "(?<=//)\\S+"))`, it will extract all text up to the first whitespace after `//`.

Comment: the reason I used rebus was that it's much easier for me to understand it. Regarding your code, unfortunately, this solution doesn't work. the reason is that at the end I want to group the same URL and see which main URL has been used more compared to others. With the code you mentioned, the result would be something like this:
www.google.com/235
www.google.com/465

; however, what I care about is only www.google.com ...

Comment: Ok, so use `"(?<=//)[^\\s/:]+"`

Comment: Great, this works better. Can you please elaborate more on the syntax you used and tell me what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply use

```r
library(stringr)
URL_var<-df[["URLs"]] 
URL_data<-data.frame(str_extract(URL_var, "(?<=//)[^\\s/:]+"))
names(URL_data)[names(URL_data) == "URL_extract...2."] <- "Main_URL"
```

Here, `stringr::str_extract` method searches for the first match in the input, and fetches the substring found. Unlike `stringr::str_match`, it cannot return submatches, so a lookbehind is used in the regex pattern, `(?<=...)`:

```
(?<=//)[^\s/:]+
```

It means:

- `(?<=//)` - match a location in the string that is immediately preceded with `//` string
- `[^\\s/:]+` - one or more (`+`) occurrences of any char but whitespace, `/` and `:`. The colon is to make sure port number is not included in the match. `/` makes sure the match stops before the first `/` and `\s` (whitespace) makes sure the match stops before the first whitespace.